# A function is executing before it should

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener, callstack

I'm having issues with a function executing before it should. In the `matchCheck` function, the `funcRemove` function is being called before the `alert('No match')`. I'm trying to have the alert called first, then the `funcRemove` function(once the alert goes away).

Here is the code:

```
const listAddCard = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
const moveElem = document.querySelector('.moves');

for(i=0; i<listAddCard.length; i++){

    listAddCard.item(i).appendChild(shuffleCards[i]);
    if(i>0){
        if(shuffleCards[i].classList.value === shuffleCards[0].classList.value){
            listAddCard.item(i).classList.add('match');
        }
    }
    else listAddCard.item(i).classList.add('match'); 
}
let turnCheck = 0;
let cardChecker = '';
let prevCard = '';
let moves = 3;

let matchCheck = function(evtObj){
  // console.log(turnCheck);
     if(turnCheck===1){
        // setTimeout(function(){}, 1000);
        if(evtObj.target.innerHTML===cardChecker){
            evtObj.target.classList.add('match');
            prevCard.classList.add('match');
        }
        else{

            alert('No match!');
        }
        funcRemove(prevCard, evtObj);
        turnCheck = 0;
        cardChecker = '';
        prevCard = '';
        moves++;
        moveElem.innerHTML = moves;
        return;
     }
     prevCard = evtObj.target;
     cardChecker = evtObj.target.innerHTML;
     turnCheck++;
 }

 let funcShow = function(evtObj){
    evtObj.target.classList.add('open');
    evtObj.target.classList.add('show');
 }

const cardDeck = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
 for(var i=0;i<cardDeck.length;i++){
     cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', funcShow);
     cardDeck[i].addEventListener('click', matchCheck);

    }

let funcRemove = function (p1,p2){

        p1.classList.remove('open');
        p1.classList.remove('show');    
        p2.target.classList.remove('open');
        p2.target.classList.remove('show');
}
```

Comment: Event listeners will fire in the order you assign them.

Comment: Not sure how that pertains to this issue. The issue is happening in the matchCheck function. The funcRemove is executing before the alert, instead of the order in which it is written

Comment: But your description states you need the alert in matchCheck to fire before funcRemove gets called and your event listeners are in opposite order. Don't know why you need two listeners in the first place and don't just call one function from within the other or inside same event handler

Answer (score 0):

In some browsers, `alert()` is asynchronous, so the script keeps running while the message is displayed.

If you want to wait for the user to dismiss the dialog before continuing, use `confirm()` instead of `alert()`.